# Could not install Kernel. The following packages have unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg, dependencies

I already downloaded the files from these 4 links:

[https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19/amd64/linux-headers-5.19.0-051900-generic_5.19.0-051900.202207312230_amd64.deb](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19/amd64/linux-headers-5.19.0-051900-generic_5.19.0-051900.202207312230_amd64.deb)

[https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19/amd64/linux-headers-5.19.0-051900_5.19.0-051900.202207312230_all.deb](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19/amd64/linux-headers-5.19.0-051900_5.19.0-051900.202207312230_all.deb)

[https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.19.0-051900-generic_5.19.0-051900.202207312230_amd64.deb](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.19.0-051900-generic_5.19.0-051900.202207312230_amd64.deb)

[https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19/amd64/linux-modules-5.19.0-051900-generic_5.19.0-051900.202207312230_amd64.deb](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19/amd64/linux-modules-5.19.0-051900-generic_5.19.0-051900.202207312230_amd64.deb)

When I right click on them, open with another application, program installation, click install and put my password, the first and second install normally, but the third and fourth keep giving this error.

I've already tried to install from the terminal by typing these following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-unsigned-5.19.0-051900-generic 
sudo apt-get install linux-modules-5.19.0-051900-generic
```

But I get this:

```
Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-image-unsigned-5.19.0-051900-generic'
```

and

```
Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-modules-5.19.0-051900-generic'
```

I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu (22.04). What do I do now?

Comment: `sudo dpkg -i *20220731*.deb`, run the command from the same directory that has the files.

Comment: I put this command like this: `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` (with one asterisk and without that number) and it worked. I do not understand why @Doug Smythies put `20220731`. It just confused me.

Comment: I put it that way because I keep all mainline kernels in the same directory, so want to only install one at a time. If you only have the one kernel, then yes what you did was fine. Although, what I listed should have worked fine also.